# How to slice a sorted list in Jinja?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a list of dictionaries. I want to first sort that list, then only iterate over a subset of those items.

This is what I tried:

```
{% for response in responses|sort(true, attribute='response_date')[:5] %}
    <p>response</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But Jinja doesn't like this syntax, and raises the error
`TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '['`

If I don't use the `sort()` filter, the slice works. But I want to use both together.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can achieve this by wrapping your `sort` in a parentheses:

```
{% for response in (responses|sort(true, attribute='response_date'))[:5] %}
   <p>response</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6):

Can't you simply wrap `responses|sort(true, attribute='response_date')` with parentheses?

```
{% for response in (responses|sort(true, attribute='response_date'))[:5] %}
    <p>response</p>
{% endif %}
```